# Reading xml data in jsp sequentially (in required order) via jsp

Tags: xml, jsp

`

```
    <microgame> 
    <gamename>Thunderstruck2</gamename>
    <gametype>Bonus Slot</gametype>
    <imagename>/images/microgame/thunderstruck2.png</imagename>
    <provider>Microgame</provider>
    <sequence>4</sequence>
    </microgame>    <microgame> 
    <gamename>TombRaider</gamename>
    <gametype>Bonus Slot</gametype>
    <imagename>/images/microgame/tomb-raider.png</imagename>
    <provider>Microgame</provider>
    <sequence>5</sequence>
    </microgame>    <microgame> 
    <gamename>Cashapillar</gamename>
    <gametype>Video Slot</gametype>
    <imagename>/images/microgame/cashapillar.png</imagename>
    <provider>Microgame</provider>
    <sequence>1</sequence>
    </microgame>
```

`

So my question is that, I want to get the imagename depending on the sequence, like for example if the sequence =1, then I should get /images/microgame/cashapillar.png and if sequence =5 then /images/microgame/tomb-raider.png and so on.

Please can anyone help me out with this, I have been writing code for this but not getting answer as per sequence. I would be thankful if anyone could help me getting it done. Thanks

Comment: `I have been writing code for this but not getting answer as per sequence` .. could you also post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..displays a table with ***sequence no.*** and corresponding `image` at ***imgname***

```
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();    
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();    
Document doc = db.parse("../.../name.xml");    
NodeList imgN = doc.getElementsByTagName("imagename");
NodeList seq = doc.getElementsByTagName("sequence");
%>    
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Imagename vs Sequence</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <%
        ArrayList<String[]> listX=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        for(int i=0;i<=seq.getLength()-1;i++)
        {
            listX.add(new String[]{imgN.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(), seq.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue()});
        }

        Collections.sort(listX, new Comparator<String[]>() {
              public int compare(String[] first, String[] second) {
                    return (Integer.parseInt(first[1]) < Integer.parseInt(second[1]) ) ? -1: (Integer.parseInt(first[1]) > Integer.parseInt(second[1]) ) ? 1:0 ;
                  }
                });

            for(int i=0;i<=listX.size()-1;i++) {
                String[] s=listX.get(i);
        %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <img src="<%= s[0] %>" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= s[1]%>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <%
        }
        %>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: alright.. `seq_no` is the value input by a user in a .html page. this page has a **submit** action to paa the entered Sequence no. to the jsp, which in turn displays the corresponding `imagename` from the xml.
let me edit my answer and it'll be clearer..

Comment: ya thank you so much, but my requirement is like, I am getting the xml file from a url, and i have to display only the images using the sequence number. There is no input from any html. Just need to process the xml and display image file in html. That's it...

Comment: But the problem is not solved, its not in arranged manner right?? like the one with sequence =1 should come first and so on...

Comment: Oh! with `NodeList` we have only `item(i)`.. there could be a complicated way by storing `sequence no.` and their `index` in a 2D array and then `sort-n-display`. therefore, something other than `NodeList` might be required...

Comment: Ok that's really awesome sunbabaphu, Thanks to you. :-)